# Cannot use `systemctl --user` due to "Failed to get D-bus connection: permission denied"

Tags: systemd, systemctl, dbus

I'm trying to set up user-level services, using [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/906224) to a similar question. I have create the required files and rebooted.

I'm making progress because I now get "Failed to get D-bus connection: permission denied" when it was "Failed to get D-bus connection: connection refused", but I'm stumped because I don't know what object it is trying to access (file? socket?) and so cannot even check current permissions. Any ideas?

So far I have added:

```
loginctl enable-linger userservice
```

#### /usr/lib/systemd/user/dbus.service (-rw-r--r-- root root)

```
[Unit]
Description=D-Bus User Message Bus
Requires=dbus.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
ExecReload=/usr/bin/dbus-send --print-reply --session --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.ReloadConfig

[Install]
Also=dbus.socket
```

#### /usr/lib/systemd/user/dbus.socket (-rw-r--r-- root root)

```
[Unit]
Description=D-Bus User Message Bus Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/bus
ExecStartPost=-/bin/systemctl --user set-environment DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=%t/bus

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
Also=dbus.service
```

#### /home/userservice/.config/systemd/user/userservice.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test user-level service

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=com.wtf.service
ExecStart=/home/userservice/userservice.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Not added any links elsewhere...

To make it fail:

```
systemctl --user status
```

Edit 2018-10-25:

Added `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)` to `.bashrc`. The variable is set and now I get: `Failed to get D-us connection: no such file or directory`. Strangely, neither `man systemctl` nor `systemctl --help` mention the `--user` option, while both mention `--system` and specify that this is the default (so what are the other options).

Using RHEL 7.4 (with `systemd 219` as reported by `systemctl --version`) with SELinux.

Comment: Can you update the system? RHEL 7.5 is current. And remember that RHEL requires a subscription; do not attempt to use it without one.

Comment: Stuck on 7.4 for the time being ('recently updated from 7.2). The behemoth organization the server belongs to has all the required licenses, but is somewhat upgrade-shy.

Comment: You've enabled linger for a user named `userservice`. You need to actually log in to this account to run `systemctl --user ` commands. If these services are going to be managed by the admin, rather than by the user, you should create normal system services, not user services.

Comment: I'm using `systemctl --user` as the `userservice` user...

Comment: While logged in as `userservice`, check the value of the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable: `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Comment: Not set for userservice... I see that when I'm root, it points to `/run/user/0` and there is indeed a `/run/user/10010` (which is the uid of userservice...)

Comment: For me `sudo systemctl --user status xx` failed with "unable to connect to bus" because it was sudo but attempting to examine user services.  Needed to not run it as sudo.

Comment: `bashrc` is afair not parsed by user systemd. That's login shell specific. You have to set environment for systemd services with `EnvironmentFile` or `Environment`. It's designed that you start with an untainted env. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Comment: To answer your question where is the dbus user socket, look at user's dbus.socket file in your sample: `ListenStream=%t/bus`. %t stands for the aame value as $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, but I _think_ it's recognized even without the variable being set. If I'm mistaken, no luck: `%t/bus` turns into `/bus`, and the user hardly has a permission to create sockets in `/`.

Comment: With a recent systemd you would be able to run
`$ sudo systemctl --user -M userservice@ status`

Comment: @ErikSjölund Interesting — what version would that be? An attempt to run that under 219 (DSM running on a Synology NAS) as well as 247 (Debian for Raspberry Pi) failed, although there was no issue running it under a 'standard' Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine (with an Intel CPU). So there might be a need to do something else.

Comment: Systemd 248 introduced the syntax `systemctl --user -M lennart@ start quux`. See the file  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/6c83054c0133eb53245e479d71589dceff76cf74/NEWS#L2796-L2800

Answer (score 17):

I've noticed the tableau server uses --user systemd services - they even have a note about this in their docs:
https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/systemd_user_service_error.htm

> The systemd user service is not used as commonly as the normal systemd
> process manager. Red Hat disabled the systemd user service in RHEL 7
> (and thereby all distros that come from RHEL, like CentOS, Oracle
> Linux 7, Amazon Linux 2). However, RedHat has assured Tableau that
> running the systemd user service is supported as long as the service
> is re-enabled.

How they do it (example is with a userid 29575)

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/user@29575.service
[Unit]
Description=User Manager for UID %i
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
# These are present in the RHEL8 version of this file except that the unit is Requires, not Wants.
# It's listed as Wants here so that if this file is used in a RHEL7 settings, it will not fail.
# If a user upgrades from RHEL7 to RHEL8, this unit file will continue to work until it's
# deleted the next time they upgrade Tableau Server itself.
After=user-runtime-dir@%i.service
Wants=user-runtime-dir@%i.service

[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
User=%i
PAMName=systemd-user
Type=notify
# PermissionsStartOnly is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of systemd
# This is required for all systemd versions prior to version 231
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/loginctl enable-linger %i
ExecStart=-/lib/systemd/systemd --user
Slice=user-%i.slice
KillMode=mixed
Delegate=yes
TasksMax=infinity
Restart=always
RestartSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After you create that file:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable user@29575.service
systemctl start user@29575.service
```

And you'll need to set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR in env of that user via bashrc or similar:

```
[ -z "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}" ] && export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -ru)
```

I've tested in on a recent RHEL 7.8 and it works as expected, I can run "systemctl --user status" as my user after doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Klaas - this is exactly, what I was looking for. Pulling my hairs out trying to understand, how to get `systemd --user` to run on RHEL7. I'd add, that using of _numeric IDs_ is not necessary -- you can use the actual user _name_ and the `%i` inside will still be substituted accordingly. Numeric IDs _may be_ faster -- or safer -- if your user-mapping is network based, but they are ugly :(

Comment: for completness: I am not sure this is actually supported:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3461241
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1173278#c1

Comment: This also works with Amazon Linux instances.

Comment: @xenoid amazing! This actually fixed the issue on DSM 7.1 (a Linux variant based on... well, Debian, I guess — used by all Synology NAS). Synology are careful to launch as few services as possible, both because of the lack of performance from the ARM chips they use, as well as reduced memory. Nevertheless, it has a full `systemd` configuration — it's just that 'most' things (especially those that could be abused easily...) are disabled by default.

Comment: Awesome. Needed this for https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2sd and got it, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

So there's a long standing issue where the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable doesn't get set properly, or at all, when users log in, and therefore can't access the user D-Bus. This happens when the user logs in via some other method than the local graphical console.

You can work around this by adding to the user's `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
```

Then log out and back in.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be sufficient, but I'm starting to wonder if systemd 219 is enough to support user services. Please see augmented question.

Comment: @xenoid Just to be clear, you _have_ rebooted the system, right? Or at least restarted systemd-logind?

Comment: Yes, rebooted several times since. But I wonder if we are looking at the right things, since `/run/user/10010` remains empty (and `/run/user/0` is empty too).

Answer (score 6):

You should be aware of how the PAM works.

If you login in the system using either of

1. graphical session
2. login on terminal (username and password)
3. ssh

then the PAM machinery will call `pam_systemd`, and this will setup all needed hooks to use `systemctl`; if you switch user using `sudo` or `su`, this will not happen.

This is deliberate , see
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237

What's weird is that actually `/etc/pam.d/su` includes `/etc/pam.d/common-session` that contains an invocation of `pam_systemd` but this fails, indeed the `/var/log/auth.log` says:

> pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session

Currently, a good way is to use `ssh` to connect to the same machine but as another user, something like `ssh user@localhost`.

Answer (score 4):

systemd 248 (relased March 2021) introduced the syntax

`systemctl --user -M username@ status`

(that command needs to be run as root)

For example

```
[myuser@laptop ~]$ sudo systemctl --user -M testuser@ status
● testuser@
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Thu 2022-11-03 22:59:10 CET; 164ms ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1492.slice/user@1492.service
           ├─init.scope
           │ ├─ 21922 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │ └─ 21929 "(sd-pam)"
           └─session.slice
             └─dbus-broker.service
               ├─ 21950 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope user
               └─ 21951 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id fa369ab69fcf4e54ad8a274517ea5096 --max-bytes 100000000000000 --max-fds 25000000000000 --max-matches 5000000000
```

Alternatively you could also open a new interactive login session

```
[myuser@laptop ~]$ sudo machinectl shell testuser@
Connected to the local host. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.
[testuser@laptop ~]$ systemctl --user status
● laptop
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Thu 2022-11-03 22:56:50 CET; 57s ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1492.slice/user@1492.service
           └─init.scope
             ├─ 21799 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
             └─ 21806 "(sd-pam)"
```

#### "sudo -u username -i" does not create a systemd login session

**su** is "*not a tool for opening a completely new login session*"
according to https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237  (I assume sudo is related to su. Just running sudo to become another user will no start that user's systemd daemon)

I tried out a few examples on a **Fedora 36** with **systemd 250**:

##### Example "sudo -u username -i"

```
[myuser@laptop ~]$ sudo useradd test1
[myuser@laptop ~]$ sudo -u test1 -i
[test1@laptop ~]$ pgrep -u $USER -l
25217 bash
[test1@laptop ~]$ env | grep XDG
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/test1/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
[test1@laptop ~]$
```

##### Example "sudo machinectl shell username@"

```
[myuser@laptop ~]$ sudo useradd test2
[myuser@laptop ~]$ sudo machinectl shell test2@
Connected to the local host. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.
[test2@laptop ~]$ pgrep -u $USER -l
25086 bash
25091 systemd
25100 (sd-pam)
25115 (sd-pam)
[test2@laptop ~]$ env | grep XDG
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_SESSION_ID=51
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1494
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/test2/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
[test2@laptop ~]$ ls -l $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus
srw-rw-rw-. 1 test2 test2 0 Nov  4 08:42 /run/user/1494/bus
[test2@laptop ~]$
```

Reference:

Relevant lines from the **systemd** 248 release notes:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/6c83054c0133eb53245e479d71589dceff76cf74/NEWS#L2796-L2800