# How can I talk to another user's systemd user process?

Tags: linux, systemd

From a script that runs as root, I'd like to start a systemd user service.

I've tried the most obvious thing:

`sudo -u $user systemctl --user <etc>`

but I get `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory` - I assume this is referring to the dbus system bus.

Do I need to set `DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS`? How would I find out what to set it to?

Or is there a different way to interact with another user's systemd?

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to start the service at boot, and you don't want to run it as a system service under a non-root user?

Comment: Both correct. 

The actual context is that I want to start a user service from NetworkManager's "dispatcher" when it connects to a VPN.

Comment: But the user is not logged in at the time?

Comment: Yeah, the user is logged in and their `systemd --user` is running

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/937012/126632 as I suspect your issue is closely related to that.

Comment: Hmm, setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR didn't change the result. I also checked `env | grep /run/user` as `$user` to see if there was anything similar that might be influencing how `systemctl` connects to `systemd`. I found XDG_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS but setting that also had no effect.